# AttributeError: module 'odbc' has no attribute 'connect' - python with pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pyodbc

I am very new to python and I just can't seem to find an answer to this error. When I run the code below I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'odbc' has no attribute 'connect'
```

However, the error only shows in eclipse. There's no problem if I run it via command line. I am running python 3.5. What am I doing wrong?

```
try:
    import pyodbc
except ImportError:
    import odbc as pyodbc

# Specifying the ODBC driver, server name, database, etc. directly
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=PXLstr,17;DATABASE=Dept_MR;UID=guest;PWD=password')
```

The suggestion to remove the try...except block did not work for me. Now the actual import is throwing the error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a\workspace\TestPyProject\src\helloworld.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyodbc
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 105, in <module>
    from .base import MSExecutionContext, MSDialect, VARBINARY
```

I do have pyodbc installed and the import and connect works fine with the command line on windows.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `pyodbc` module is not importing in your `try` / `except` block. I would highly recommend not putting import statements in `try` blocks. First, you would want to make sure you have `pyodbc` installed (`pip install pyodbc`), preferably in a `virtualenv`, then you can do something like this:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=PXLstr,17;DATABASE=Dept_MR;UID=guest;PWD=password')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT 1')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

If you're running on Windows (it appears so, given the `DRIVER=` parameter), take a look at `virtualenvwrapper-win` for managing Windows Python virtual environments: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It now shows errors with the `import pyodbc` statement - I updated my question above to show the errors.

Comment: Thanks you, your answer helped me to find the core of the problem. Now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Flipper's answer helped to establish that the problem was with referencing an incorrect library in External Libraries list in eclipse. After fixing it, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your python file? If you inadvertently name it as 'pyodbc.py', you got that error. Because it tries to import itself instead of the intended pyodbc module.

Comment: It looks like the file is `helloworld.py` in the stack trace provided.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution!
simply install and use 'pypyodbc' instead of 'pyodbc'!
I have my tested example as below. change your data for SERVER_NAME and DATA_NAME and DRIVER. also put your own records.good luck!

```
import sys
import pypyodbc as odbc

records = [
    ['x', 'Movie', '2020-01-09', 2020],
    ['y', 'TV Show', None, 2019]
]

DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server'
SERVER_NAME = '(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB'
DATABASE_NAME = 'D:\ASPNET\SHOJA.IR\SHOJA.IR\APP_DATA\DATABASE3.MDF'

conn_string = f"""
    Driver={{{DRIVER}}};
    Server={SERVER_NAME};
    Database={DATABASE_NAME};
    Trust_Connection=yes;
"""

try:
    conn = odbc.connect(conn_string)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('task is terminated')
    sys.exit()
else:
    cursor = conn.cursor()


insert_statement = """
    INSERT INTO NetflixMovies
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
"""

try:
    for record in records:
        print(record)
        cursor.execute(insert_statement, record)
except Exception as e:
    cursor.rollback()
    print(e.value)
    print('transaction rolled back')
else:
    print('records inserted successfully')
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
finally:
    if conn.connected == 1:
        print('connection closed')
        conn.close()
```